# ElasticSearch get the first time that item is shown

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

In my case, I'm doing an *action* each time (PullRequest) and saving the **action results** in ElasticSearch.

I want to build a query that will help me to get the **results changes** in every *action*.

For example, the data can represent this case:

| PR sortable ID | Results | Change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "foo", "bar" | "foo", "bar" |
| 2 | "foo", "bar" |  |
| 3 | "foo", "bar", "eggs" | "eggs" |
| 4 | "bar", "eggs" | -"foo" |

In this example, the `foo` and `bar` first showed in `PR 1`, so they related to it.

`PR 2` didn't change the state, so nothing related to it.

`PR 3` added `eggs`.

`PR 4` removed the `foo`, **so this result (`foo`) should be filtered from the end result** (and not see it in `PR 1`, too).

**The final result should be `PR 1: "bar", PR 3: "eggs"`**

### **In one sentence:**

> For each **result** exists in the latest **PR**, I want to know in which **PR** this **result** started to be.

Since the order of the PRs is important, the question is how to save the **action results** from the PR *as is*, and get the answer of "which **PR** this **result** started to be" on-demand.

---

If I will analyze the starting point of the result **before** inserting it to the DB, it might accidentally break if I will run the process of calculation for `PR 4` before `PR 3`.

I understand that I will probably need to solve part of the mission with my programming language, and we already do that in more complicated cases. The question is, how much can I give to the *ElasticSearch Engine* to do the work and the calculation for me?

---

**Two options to generate the data:**

I'm welcome for more ideas. These are just the options I can think about.

1. Save each result as a document with all the context (PR, for example) in it:

```
POST test/_bulk
{ "index":{"_type": "_doc"} }
{ "PR":1,"result":"foo" }

{ "index":{"_type": "_doc"} }
{ "PR":1,"result":"bar" }

{ "index":{"_type": "_doc"} }
{ "PR":2,"result":"foo" }

{ "index":{"_type": "_doc"} }
{ "PR":2,"result":"bar" }

{ "index":{"_type": "_doc"} }
{ "PR":3,"result":"foo" }

{ "index":{"_type": "_doc"} }
{ "PR":3,"result":"bar" }

{ "index":{"_type": "_doc"} }
{ "PR":3,"result":"eggs" }

{ "index":{"_type": "_doc"} }
{ "PR":4,"result":"bar" }

{ "index":{"_type": "_doc"} }
{ "PR":4,"result":"eggs” }
```

(Each doc is a different document, the `_id` is automatically generated by ElasticSearch. Sum: 9 documents)

2. Save each PR as a document, with all the **action results** inside it:

```
POST test/_bulk
{"index":{"_type":"_doc"}}
{"PR":1,"result":["foo","bar"]}

{"index":{"_type":"_doc"}}
{"PR":2,"result":["foo","bar"]}

{"index":{"_type":"_doc"}}
{"PR":3,"result":["foo","bar","eggs"]}

{"index":{"_type":"_doc"}}
{"PR":4,"result":["bar","eggs"]}
```

(Each doc is a different document, the `_id` is automatically generated by ElasticSearch. Sum: 4 documents)

Comment: Your commands to generate the data is missing the `_id` on the command line, I think that's important to know because the solution kind of depends on that. Are you indexing all those separately (auto ID generation) or do you have one document per PR or a single document that evolves over time ?

Comment: @Val I'm not sure about the `_id`. You see two options to index: one is in the PR context, and all the results are in it, and one is a document per result, with the PR as a field (it looks the same, I know. The context is the important part)
The `_id` can be the PR number for the first option, and I don't know, auto id for the results option,

Comment: @Val Thanks, I'm really open to ideas. I don't think updating an existing document is a good idea for me, because the order is important here, and I don't want to fail because PR 4 updated the document before PR 3, accidentally.

Comment: The other question is whether you need to keep the whole history to be searchable or only the latest state (i.e. latest PR)? I had to design something pretty close to this, but there are still some blind spots here, namely whether each PR needs to stay in the same "context" or whether they are all independent from each other (which goes back to the discussion regarding the `_id` which I think is central here to find the right solution)

Comment: Today we are working with saving the latest state, which means that every time there is a new PR, we are recalculating the state.
It is done on the PR phase, before the DB.
Now I trying to think about another approach- saving the data from the PR as is, and trying to understand the first result shown, on demand.

Comment: I think I don't know why is the `_id` is important here.

Comment: The id is important because in the first bulk you provided you'd end up with 9 different documents, while in the second bulk with 4... I'm trying to figure out if all of these updates should related to a single document that is getting updated or not, hence why the notion of id is important. Is it a single document that gets updated each time or several documents (one per PR) that evolve over time in isolation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235622/discussion-between-baruchiro-and-val).

Answer (score 0):

> For each **result** exists in the latest **PR**, I want to know in which **PR** this **result** started to be.

Assume you saved a document for each PR, which includes all the results in it.

We will start with two requests. First, get the **results** from the latest **PR**:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "size": 1,
  "sort": [
    {
      "PR": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}

Response:
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "PR" : 4,
          "result" : [
            "bar",
            "eggs"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, in your code, you take the `result` from the response and you get `bar` and `eggs`.

For the second query, you need to aggregate those values to get the first **PR**. Since the **PR** is sorted, you can use `min` aggregation, after `filters` aggregation to split the buckets by expected **results**:

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "result.keyword": "bar"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "result.keyword": "eggs"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_result": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "bar": {
            "term": {
              "result.keyword": "bar"
            }
          },
          "eggs": {
            "term": {
              "result.keyword": "eggs"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "first_PR": {
          "min": {
            "field": "PR"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Response:
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "by_result" : {
      "buckets" : {
        "bar" : {
          "doc_count" : 4,
          "first_PR" : {
            "value" : 1.0
          }
        },
        "eggs" : {
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "first_PR" : {
            "value" : 3.0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From the response, the `aggregations.by_result.buckets.{result}.first_PR.value` will be:

- `bar`: PR `1`
- `eggs`: PR `3`

---

What is missing?

- It requires two queries. Can we get the **latest PR results** and use them in the same query?
- What if a **result** showed in PRs 1,2 and then, didn't showed in PR 3, but showed again in PR 4? In that case, we need to get **PR 4** as a result.

Comment: Consider using histogram aggregation, with derivation aggregation to get the change of the result existence.
Another option is to use a moving function.